# Disabling unicode interpretation for keycode sequences

Tags: fedora, keyboard, input

When typing the character combination <kbd>^</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd> (one after the other, not simultaneously) I do not get these two characters, but Unicode point `U+00B2`, aka `²`. Same is true for <kbd>^</kbd>,<kbd>4</kbd>  => `U+2074` => `⁴` etc.
My locale is set to English, while using a German keyboard. I would like to retain the normal character behaviour, e.g. typing ä,ö,ü,ß directly, but disable interpretation of multi-keycode sequences.

I run Fedora 31 (Workstation Edition) with GNOME 3.34.4.

Does anyone how to disable this interpretation?

Edit:
Output of `xev` when typing <kbd>^</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x2cd, subw 0x0, time 33006949, (941,-29), root:(1091,183),
    state 0x10, keycode 49 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x2cd, subw 0x0, time 33007045, (941,-29), root:(1091,183),
    state 0x10, keycode 49 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x2cd, subw 0x0, time 33007677, (941,-29), root:(1091,183),
    state 0x10, keycode 11 (keysym 0x32, 2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (32) "2"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (32) "2"
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x2cd, subw 0x0, time 33007677, (941,-29), root:(1091,183),
    state 0x10, keycode 0 (keysym 0xb2, twosuperior), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 11
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 b2) "²"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x2cd, subw 0x0, time 33007781, (941,-29), root:(1091,183),
    state 0x10, keycode 11 (keysym 0x32, 2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (32) "2"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: _Are_ you in fact typing a caret character and then a 2 character? Or are you actually typing a single chord involving the ⎈ Strg key?  Caret notation is ambiguous here.  You can use <kbd> and </kbd>  tags here to show what actual keys you type.

Comment: @JdeBP clarified it, thanks for the hint. Also, it creates an underline under the caret until I hit the next key, then the actual unicode char is inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'de+nodeadkeys')]"
```

It was `'de'` before that, lacking the `+nodeadkeys` part.